# SpringBoot: @Validated and @PreDestroy Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-validator

I have a Spring service with `@PreDestroy` method which calls another service

```
@Service
public class DestroyMe {
  public final ValidService service;
  private SomeDto dto;
  @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        service.stop(dto);
  }
}
```

The `ValidService` its an interface with `@Validated` class level annotation

```
@Validated
public interface ValidService {
  public void stop(@Valid SomeDto dto);
}
```

Also there's implementation class of this interface (with `@Service` annotation).

Validation works correctly in runtime, but when SprinBoot application terminates, it calls the `destroy` method which calls the `service.stop(dto)` and I get this error:

`Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)`.

Clicking on `defaultValidator` in IDE brings me into `public static LocalValidatorFactoryBean defaultValidator()` of `ValidationAutoConfiguration` class.

If I remove the `@Validated` annotation from the `ValidatedService` all works correctly but there's no service's input validation.
Looks like Spring is trying to create the validator bean ad-hoc to validate the input to `stop` method but it's not possible to do this in destroy phase.

How to solve this problem?

**EDIT 1**
Here is the code to reproduce this behavior: https://github.com/smacz/predestroy

Answer (score 0):

A fix would be to replace the `@PreDestroy` annotation with   `@EventListener(ContextClosedEvent.class)`, if this makes sense in the context of your application.

**Background**

Beans are destroyed one by one. So when your Bean `DestroyMe` is being destroyed, it might happen, that the `Validator`-bean has already been destroyed. But a `Validator` bean is required, as the `ValidService` is annotated with `@Validated`. So Spring tries to load that bean from the application context. As the bean is not there, it tries to create a new instance for that bean, but this is not allowed while the application context is being shut down, as the exception states.

By switching from a pre-destroy method to an event listener which listens for the context closed event, one can run code, before any beans are destroyed.